# How to detect external files being dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

is there any way to find the dragging happening inside or outside from the browser?

```
$(ele)
     .on('dragover', function(e){
             //show dropzone   
     })
     .on('dragleave', function(e){

            //close drop zone    
     })
     .on('drop', function(e){
            //handle droped file   
     });
```

the above events are triggered files being draged outside or internal elements(or text) being dragging. I need to stop trigger above events when dragging happening internally.